# Create new model and store contact form details in database - magento

Tags: php, magento

Error: Fatal Error:  Call to a member function save() on a non-object.
IndexController.php

```
           $model = Mage::getModel('contacts/contacts');
           $model->setGuestName( trim($post['name']) );
           $model->setGuestEmail(trim($post['email']));
           $model->setGuestTelephone(trim($post['telephone']));
           $model->setGuestComments(trim($post['comment']));
           $model->setGuestAttachment(trim($post['attachment']));
           $model->Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save( );
```

Config.xml

```
          <models>
          <contacts>
          <class>Mage_Contacts_Model</class>
          <resourceModel>Contacts_Mysql4</resourceModel>        
          </contacts>
          <contacts_Mysql4>
          <class>Mage_Contacts_Model_Mysql4</class>
          <entities>
          <contacts>
          <table>contact_details</table>
          </contacts>
          </entities>                
          </contacts_Mysql4>
          </models>
```

Comment: ok, great. Whats your question? :)

Comment: It should be  `$model->save();`

Comment: I changed it but still getting error..                                Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object in                                                           {main}( ) \index.php:0
Mage::run( ) \index.php:87
Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) ..\Mage.php:684
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( ) ..\App.php:354
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( ) ..\Front.php:172
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) Standard.php:250
Mage_Contacts_IndexController->postAction( )Action.php:418
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save( ) IndexController.php:126